# Foxit Reader uses 30% CPU unless run as root?

Tags: pdf, foxitreader

I downloaded Foxit Reader (64bit: https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) and installed it but ran into a problem. I had to switch from Wayland (Gnome vanilla) to Xorg to install it but when I run it now it immediately uses 25-30% of my CPU (with a relatively low memory footprint of of less than 100 MB). If I start it from terminal I get infinite rows saying:

```
Adding Dnt Data last error is: "attempt to write a readonly database Unable to fetch row" Has delive node, commit it to db
```

I can use Foxit but it eats up my CPU, could this be a problem of user rights (hence it works when run as root?) or can I only run it under Xorg or do you guys have another idea?

Comment: Foxit is proprietary software, and has it's own support channel. Using 25%-30% of CPU, incompatibility with Wayland, and the permissions problem seems like reportable bugs (to Foxit, not us).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was just because it runs perfectly fine on my workstation (also Ubuntu 18.10, also wayland, no idea what could be different on the laptop, maybe graphic drivers?)